# Adding module gives me a resolve dependency error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-module

I am new to android programming and when I try to add this module

https://github.com/FreesoulApps/PreviewAndroid

I get unable to resolve dependency on line 78 on my build.gradle file:

[image]

**RELEVANT INFORMATION**

Module to be added setting.gradle file :
[image]

The reason why I want to implement it as a module is because I would like to edit the src files from this dependency.

***ANY HELP IS APPERCIATED***

Comment: Can you share your repo with this problem ?

Comment: The repo hasn't been updated since 2017 , so i assumed the creator has forgotten about it

Comment: Am I right that you created you app project, created new module, copied source code of PreviewAndroid to new module ?

Comment: yes, because if it's not a module i cannot edit the source code.

Comment: Ok, can you share your project ?